# While resolving module `react-native/Libraries/Core/Devtools/getDevServer`, the Haste package `react-native` was found

Tags: react-native, expo

Building JavaScript bundle: error
ERROR
20:56
While resolving module `react-native/Libraries/Core/Devtools/getDevServer`, the Haste package `react-native` was found. However the module `Libraries/Core/Devtools/getDevServer` could not be found within the package. Indeed, none of these files exist:

- `C:\Users\User\Desktop\repos\native\react-native\Libraries\Core\Devtools\getDevServer(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)`
- `C:\Users\User\Desktop\repos\native\react-native\Libraries\Core\Devtools\getDevServer\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)`
  INFO
  20:57
  Building JavaScript bundle

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I have been with this issue since yesterday as well.
I did the following steps to fix it:

- Using nvm, switched to the latest LTS Node version
- Removed `node_modules`, `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json` and `.expo` folders
- Running `yarn` or `npm cache clean`
- Reinstall the dependencies

If that all fails, try re-creating your project by running

```
expo init app-name
```

***Note:*** You have to double check if the current `expo-cli` version you're using matches with React Native; you can check [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/#each-expo-sdk-version-depends-on-a).